# urlparse does not raise exception for an invalid url

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I have the following code, which is supposed to check if an entered url is valid:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import urllib.parse

# ...

def checkValidURL(someURL):
    try:
        parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(someURL)
        isURL = True
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid URL!")
        sys.exit(0)

# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    checkValidURL(someURL)
```

If an invalid URL is entered, for example: `someURL="http://ijfjiör@@@a:43244434::"` it should raise a `ValueError` as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

> Characters in the netloc attribute that decompose under NFKC normalization (as used by the IDNA encoding) into any of /, ?, #, @, or : will raise a ValueError. If the URL is decomposed before parsing, no error will be raised.

However, no exception is raised and the URL seems to be valid. 
 
Is there anything I am doing wrong or is there any other way to check the validity of an URL?

Comment: The phrase `If the URL is decomposed before parsing, no error will be raised` makes me think that perhaps an exception would not be raised in every case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That what I thought too, but I'm not sure what exactly is meant by "decomposed" since I'm not altering the URL or doing anything beforehand with the URL at all.

Comment: Can you try an invalid URL which only uses characters allowed in a URL?  For example, what happens if you try: `http://www?.google.com` ?

Comment: And that is a valid URL indeed! :-) ```www``` is the hostname and ```.google.com``` is the query. There's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

Your URL doesn't decompose into a string which contains a prohibited character, so the quotation is not at all relevant here.

The language in the quote is strictly about disallowing the use of [internationalized domain name encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) like `http://xn--foo/` to produce something like `http://?/` and since you are not doing that here, no `ValueError` is generated or indeed to be expected.

(Sorry, not in a place where I can create a genuine working example.)

Comment: Maybe `http://xn-?-vbb/` for a trivial but hopefully at least vaguely illustrative example. See also https://www.punycoder.com/

Comment: I'm not sure if I got what you're saying, correct me if I'm wrong.
If I put an unmatched square bracket in the URL, an error is raised, which is also stated in the documentation, so that seems to work: 
> Unmatched square brackets in the netloc attribute will raise a ValueError.

But isn't it supposed to also raise a `ValueError` for my URL? I can vaguely remember to have used urlparsed in python2 a few years ago, which would raise an exception for characters like `/, ?, #, @, or :` just like in my example...
How else would you verify a URL?

Comment: Your URL `http://xn-?-vbb/` also doesn't raise a `ValueError`. That is `parsed_url`: `ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='xn-', path='', params='', query='-vbb/', fragment=''`

Comment: What I'm saying is that the documentation you quote is about a condition which your test case does not meet. So my simple answer to "why don't I get a `ValueError` for this specific reason" is that this specific reason is not present here.

Comment: The real trick would be to get something like `xn--x-foo` where the `foo` part contains Punycode which represents one of the prohibited characters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the [python validators module](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-validators.url) would be a better fit for your use case?

```
$ python3

>>> 
>>> 
>>> import validators
>>> 
>>> validators.url("http://ijfjiör@@@a:43244434::")
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://ijfjiör@@@a:43244434::', 'public': False})
>>> 
>>> validators.url("http://www.google.com:8080/")
True
>>> 
>>> validators.url("http://www.我愛你.com:8080/你好")
True
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was initially looking for. I used `urlparse` due to the fact that I can vaguely remember to have used it in Python 2 for URL Validation, which worked fine as far as I can remember. I guess I will go with that solution then, thanks.